# Objects interacting with listeners in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, listener

I'm making a simple program that creates and rolls a die. There is a separate Die class which includes an argumented constructor that takes as a parameter the number of sides the die should have. What I'm having trouble with is when to create the die object. As a field I feel is too soon because I have to specify parameters in the listener method, and when it's created within the listener method, it can't be modified again in outside when the die object is called upon again to be rolled.

```
`package question1;



    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
   This frame shows a data set and its statistics.
 */
    public class DieGUI extends JFrame
    {  
        private static int WINDOW_WIDTH = 450;
        private static int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 250;
        private JLabel message;
        private JTextField Sides;
        private JTextArea data;
        private JButton create;
        private JButton rollButton;
        private static JPanel panel;
        private int numSides;

    //declare data fields here (GUI Components and other data fields)

    public DieGUI()
    {       


        message = new JLabel("Enter number of sides");
        Sides = new JTextField(5);
        create = new JButton("Create");
        rollButton = new JButton("Roll Current Die");
        data = new JTextArea(10, 30);



        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(message);
        panel.add(Sides);
        panel.add(create);
        panel.add(rollButton);
        panel.add(data);

        //Initialize data fields and construct GUI  




    //supporting methods are here.
    create.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                numSides = Integer.parseInt(Sides.getText());

    data.append("Note that creating a new die     replaces the current one");

                Die die = new Die(numSides);
                data.append("\n" + die.toString());
            }
        });         

    rollButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg1){
        die.roll();
        data.append("\n" + die.getSideUp());
    }
    });
        }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       

        JFrame frame = new DieGUI();
        frame.setTitle("Dice GUI!");
        frame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);
    }}`
```

Comment: You could create the object outside and later on set the amount of faces via a set method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are any number of ways to solve this:

1. Add the die as field with a default number of faces.  Add a method,
   `setFaceCount()` to the `Die` class to update this as necessary from
   your listener.
2. Add a die field, but set to null as default.  Replace die
       in your listener.

Regardless, you'll need to create a die field, so that it can be accessed outside of the scope of your listener method.  How you design it will depend on what behavior you want in your GUI.

Comment: Since the text field has a default value from the start, I suggest not using `null` but simply using the initial field value as initial die size, e.g. `private Die die = new Die(5);`